# Expected an indented block Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Попробовал сделать игру типа Game Of Life, но после написание кода выдает ошибку `Expected an indented block`, никак не могу найти ответ на вопрос. Перед этим выдавало ошибку места перед строкой и как только получилось исправить одну выдает тут же 2, замкнутый круг получается. Буду очень признателен за вашу помощь.

Вот код:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, Frame, BOTH, NORMAL, HIDDEN
root = Tk()
win_width = 350
win_height= 370
config_string = "{0}x{1}".format(win_width, win_height +32)
root.geometry(config_string)
cell_size = 20
canvas = Canvas(root, height=win_height)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
field_height = win_height / a
field_width = win_width / a

cell_matrix = []
for i in xrange(field_height):
    for j in xrange(field_width):
        square = canvas.create_rectangle(2+ cell_size*j, 2+ cell_size*i, cell_size
                                          + cell_size*j - 2, cell_size + cell_size*i - 2, fill="green")
        canvas.itemconfig(square, state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid', '0'))
        cell_matrix.append(squre)
        fict_square = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,0,0, state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid','o'))
        cell_matrix.append(fict_square)

        frame = Frame(root)
        btn1 = Button(frame, text='Eval', command = step)
        btn2 = Button(frame, text='Clear', command = clear)
        btn1.pack(side='left')
        btn2.pack(side='right')
        frame.pack(side='bottom')
        canvas.bind('', drav_a)
        root.mainloop()

        def refresh():
         for i in xrange(field_height):
            for j in xrange(field_width):
                k = 0
                for i_shift in xrange(-1,2):
                    for j_shift in xrange(-1,2):
                        if (canvas.gettags(cell_matrix[addr(i + i_shift, j + j_shift)])[0] =='vis'and (i_shift != 0 or j_shift !=0)):
                            k += 1
                            current_tag = canvas.gettags(cell_matrix[addr(i, j)])[0]
                            if(k == 3):
                                canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)], tags=(current_tag, 'to_vis'))
                                if(k == 4):
                                    canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)],tags=(current_tag, 'to_hid'))
                                    if(k == 2 and canvas.gettags (sm[addr(i,j)])[0]=='vis'):
    canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)],tags=(current_tag, 'to_vis')) #Перед этой строкой выдает ошибку  
            def repaint():
                for i in xrange(field_height):
                    for j in xrange(field_width):
                        if(canvas.gettags(sm[addr(i,j)])[1]=='to_hid'):
                            canvas.itemconfig(sm[addr(i,j)], state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid','0'))
                            if (canvas.gettags(sm[addr(i,j)])[1] == 'to_vis'):
                                canvas.itemconfig(sm[addr(i,j)],state=NORMAL, tags=('vis','0'))
                                def step():
                                    refresh()
                                    repaint()
                    def draw_a(e):
                        ii = (e.y - 3) /cell_size
                        jj = (e.x - 3) /cell_size
                        canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(ii, jj)], state=NORMAL, tags='vis')
                        def addr(ii, jj):
                            if(ii < 0 or jj <0 or ii >=field_height or jj >= field_width):
                                return len(cell_matrix) - 1
                            else:
                                return ii*(win_width/a) + jj
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подправил отступы, но проблемы еще будут с `2.`

Замечания:

1. не создавайте вложенные функции таких размеров, особенно в циклах.
2. PyCharm подсветил кучу неизвестных переменных, функций: `a`, `cell_matrix.append(squre)`, `step`, `clear`, `drav_a`, `addr`, `sm`. Большая часть, мне кажется, простые опечатки.
3. Условия if не нужно оборачивать в скобки
4. Не создавайте кучу вложенных друг в друга циклов, визуально это вырвиглазно, лучше обернуть часть этих циклов в функцию – так короче и понятнее будет.
5. Еще вам желательно полистать [pep8](http://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html) – указания как оформлять код на питоне, после которого код станет лучше

Код:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button, Frame, BOTH, NORMAL, HIDDEN

root = Tk()
win_width = 350
win_height= 370
config_string = "{0}x{1}".format(win_width, win_height +32)
root.geometry(config_string)
cell_size = 20
canvas = Canvas(root, height=win_height)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
field_height = win_height / a
field_width = win_width / a

cell_matrix = []
for i in xrange(field_height):
    for j in xrange(field_width):
        square = canvas.create_rectangle(2+ cell_size*j, 2+ cell_size*i, cell_size
                                          + cell_size*j - 2, cell_size + cell_size*i - 2, fill="green")
        canvas.itemconfig(square, state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid', '0'))
        cell_matrix.append(squre)
        fict_square = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,0,0, state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid','o'))
        cell_matrix.append(fict_square)

        frame = Frame(root)
        btn1 = Button(frame, text='Eval', command = step)
        btn2 = Button(frame, text='Clear', command = clear)
        btn1.pack(side='left')
        btn2.pack(side='right')
        frame.pack(side='bottom')
        canvas.bind('', drav_a)
        root.mainloop()

        def refresh():
            for i in xrange(field_height):
                for j in xrange(field_width):
                    k = 0
                    for i_shift in xrange(-1,2):
                        for j_shift in xrange(-1,2):
                            if (canvas.gettags(cell_matrix[addr(i + i_shift, j + j_shift)])[0] =='vis'and (i_shift != 0 or j_shift !=0)):
                                k += 1
                                current_tag = canvas.gettags(cell_matrix[addr(i, j)])[0]
                                if(k == 3):
                                    canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)], tags=(current_tag, 'to_vis'))
                                    if(k == 4):
                                        canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)],tags=(current_tag, 'to_hid'))
                                        if(k == 2 and canvas.gettags (sm[addr(i,j)])[0]=='vis'):
                                            canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(i,j)],tags=(current_tag, 'to_vis'))
            def repaint():
                for i in xrange(field_height):
                    for j in xrange(field_width):
                        if(canvas.gettags(sm[addr(i,j)])[1]=='to_hid'):
                            canvas.itemconfig(sm[addr(i,j)], state=HIDDEN, tags=('hid','0'))
                            if (canvas.gettags(sm[addr(i,j)])[1] == 'to_vis'):
                                canvas.itemconfig(sm[addr(i,j)],state=NORMAL, tags=('vis','0'))
                                def step():
                                    refresh()
                                    repaint()

                    def draw_a(e):
                        ii = (e.y - 3) /cell_size
                        jj = (e.x - 3) /cell_size
                        canvas.itemconfig(cell_matrix[addr(ii, jj)], state=NORMAL, tags='vis')
                        def addr(ii, jj):
                            if(ii < 0 or jj <0 or ii >=field_height or jj >= field_width):
                                return len(cell_matrix) - 1
                            else:
                                return ii*(win_width/a) + jj
```